# Inconsistencies while typecasting (Error: Incompatible types)

Tags: java, class, methods, interface, compiler-errors

This Program Compile without any Issue.

```
interface X{}
class A{
    public void mA(){
        System.out.println("mA of A");
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        X  ob=null;
        A a1=null;

        ob=(X) a1; //Legal
        a1=(A)ob; //Legal
    }
}
```

But Below code have issues ?

```
interface X{}
final class A{
    public void mA(){
        System.out.println("mA of A");
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        X  ob=null;
        A a1=null;

        ob=(X) a1; //Illegal
        a1=(A)ob; //Illegal
    }
}
```

```
Error:
 error: incompatible types: A cannot be converted to X
 ob=(X) a1; //Illegal
            ^
1 error
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: please change the title and give us more information on your program

Comment: Also you should give methods, classes, variables and interfaces real Names, so you dont have single characters. It just makes unnecessary work for us and for you

Comment: The error you're showing is referencing a line of code that you don't have...

Answer (score 6):

Instances of class `A` will never also be instances of `X`. However, in the first example, it is possible that `a1` is an instance of some hypothetical class that extends `A` and implements `X`, so the cast is fine.

In the second example, there are no subclasses of `A` because it is final. Since `A` does not implement `X`, there will never be an instance of `A` that is also an instance of `X`. Therefore, the compiler is smart enough to understand that the cast will always fail and so gives you an error message.